# Is there a way to render without touching .Rmd files?

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown

When I use an R script from the shell to render my bookdown document,

```
Rscript -e "bookdown::render_book('index.Rmd', 'bookdown::gitbook')"
```

it touches all of the .Rmd files. Is there a way to render without touching the files so I don't have to reload them in my editor?

My `_bookdown.yml` file is:

```
new_session: yes

rmd_files: [
 "index.Rmd",

 "encoding.Rmd",
 "includes.Rmd",
 "comments.Rmd",
 "whitespace.Rmd",

 "types.Rmd",
 "expressions.Rmd",
 "statements.Rmd",
 "blocks.Rmd",
 "user-functions.Rmd",

 "execution.Rmd",

 "transforms.Rmd",

 "syntax.Rmd"
]

before_chapter_script: "_common.R"

delete_merged_file: TRUE
```

and my `_common.R` is

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rstan)

set.seed(10101010)

options(digits = 3)

printf ",
  collapse = TRUE,
  cache = TRUE,
  out.width = "70%",
  fig.align = 'left',
  fig.width = 6,
  fig.asp = 0.618,  # 1 / phi
  fig.show = "hold"
)
```

The beginning of my `index.Rmd` file is:

```
---
title: "Stan Language Reference"
author: "Stan Development Team"
date: "Version 2.18 (May 2018)"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
output: bookdown::gitbook
documentclass: book
bibliography: [../bibtex/all.bib]
biblio-style: "apalike"
link-citations: true
fontsize: 11pt
cover-image: img/logo_tm.png
url: 'http\://mc-stan.org/'
github-repo: stan-dev/stan
monofont: "Lucida Console"
description: "Stan reference manual specifying the syntax and semantics of the Stan programming language."
---
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is a known issue that I don't have time to address yet: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/405

Answer (score 1):

[I just fixed this issue](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/commit/581bb639b273a5872e01c10d382065a80a641bf0) in **bookdown** 0.17.2 on Github. Your Rmd files will no longer be touched in future versions of **bookdown**. For now, you may install the dev version:

```r
remotes::install_github('rstudio/bookdown')
```

Comment: That's great news!  Thanks so much.